# First file created with Flutter leads to white screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I got Flutter installed. No problems with flutter doctor. Installed Dart en Flutter in Android Studio, opened a new Flutter project and chose for Flutter (and flutter dir) and wanted to try my first code in main.dart:

```
void main() {
  print('hello world');
}
```

When I try to run in Windows and browsers, they show a white screen. Also the terminal doesn't show any errors. Opening in a VDE does show some errors, but also finally leads to a white screen.

Anyone who can help me? I got the latest versions of Flutter and Android Studio. Running Android projects (with Kotlin) doesn't lead to any problems.

Comment: print statements are send to the debug console. They are put into the console as a dark aqua blue and barely noticeable.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. Even when I look really closely, I don't see anything. When I inspect the code in Chrome and search for hello, it doesn't find anything either.

Comment: To be sure the print will be logged in the vscode debug console, not in the Chrome devtools console. You can open a terminal in vscode by pressing `ctrl + backtick` . Also make sure you have a Flutter boiler plate by running `flutter create APPNAME` in your projects directory.